# Terraform module export 50 resources

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform module of `aws security groups` which creates ~50 security groups, I want to access the security group IDs in a different module of `elb`, do I need to declare an `output` per security group or is there a way to access the module's resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use output. That s the only way to pass variables between modules.

Comment: yaiks, that means I need to declare 50+ outputs! that's one output per security group since i need its ID...

Comment: If you create your sg in a single statement using `count` then you can output the list. I guess that s not the case.